# Zeppelin : Hive Interpreter not picking up details

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, hive, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zeppelin to run hive queries. Here is my use case

1. Create a Docker image with Hive, Hadoop and Zeppelin
2. Use Zeppelin REST api to query Hive from IDE

So basically, I want to connect my IDE to the Hive running inside the Docker container.

I have been able to set up the image properly and I can run the zeppelin inside my docker container. Also, I am able to interact with the Zeppelin UI using my browser

Finally, I was able to set up a Hive interpreter for Zeppelin as per

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/hive.html

Also, I am able to use Zeppelin to run Hive queries.

However, the Zeppelin Hive interpreter does not seem to have any knowledge of the data I create in Hive using the command line.

For instance, if I create a Hive table and populate some data via the command line (exec into the container and run hive commands), I am unable to see the table and data in Zeppelin.

Hive version is `2.3.2`. Here is the `hive-site.xml` I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
        <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>
  <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>root</value>
        <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>root</value>
        <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and here is the Hive interpreter I created for Zeppelin

[image]

Is this the right approach to connect to Hive running inside Docker?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Those settings look like you're connecting to Mysql, not Hive. The documentation you linked to is fine - for example, where are you setting anything to use `jdbc:hive2` address? And are you also running Mysql within the same container? You're basically making a mini VM here, not Docker in the best way

Comment: oh i see. yes, i want to have all of these services in Docker. is this not the correct approach? How should i create a virtual environment with all of these services? Should i use kubernetes and have separate Docker containers for each of these?

Comment: Docker compose should work. You don't need Kubernetes. You can see that this should already have Hadoop and Hive configured, all you would need to add would be the Zeppelin container (which already exists on DockerHub) https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: nice! i'll work on this